How to get the Application or Job details when I submit a new Job Application in Job Manager plugin for Wordpress
I have something like, after a new job application, I try to get the category of the Job I applied to, and put a check of the job category, so I can send an email.
This is my code attempt:
add_action( 'new_job_application', function( $application_id, $job_id ) {
    $category_detail=get_the_category($job_id); // $post->ID
    foreach($category_detail as $cd){
        //echo $cd->cat_name;
        if($cd->cat_name == 'INTERNAL EMPLOYMENT'){
            $message = "Well done!";
            $message .= "INTERNAL EMPLOYMENT";
            wp_mail('gaderex376@barakal.com', "Testing Email test INTERNAL EMPLOYMENT", $message);
        }
    }
}, 999, 2 );

But if I use var_dump($category_detail); I get an empty array.
Did I miss something?

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_category/: "Note: This function only returns results from the default "category" taxonomy.
For custom taxonomies use get_the_terms() ." - probably likely, that this is not using the default "category" taxonomy.

As "Job" is a custom post type, job category is a custom taxonomy for "Job" custom post type, then as
C3roe told you, get_the_category() will not work with it. Also, Instead of looping through Job category terms checking for a specific term, simply use has_term() WordPress conditional function that works with custom taxonomies and accepts term names, slugs or Ids.
